"Fake 'Please select a variation' alert on Add to Cart button in WooCommerce product variation selection"
I'm working on a custom WooCommerce product page where the user can select product variations (like size, color, etc.) and then add the product to the cart. Everything is functioning correctly, including the variation selection and the dynamic price update based on the selected variation.
However, I've encountered a problem. When a user selects a variation and clicks the 'Add to Cart' button, a fake alert appears, saying "Please select a variation," even though a valid variation has already been selected. After closing this fake alert, the product is successfully added to the cart, and a success message appears.
I want to prevent this fake alert from showing when the product is added to the cart successfully. How can I modify the event handling to ensure only the success alert is shown, and the fake alert doesn't appear?
Any help or suggestions are appreciated!
global $product;



// Get the product's default price HTML

$default_price_html = $product->get_price_html();



// Get available variations

$available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();



$product_id = $product->get_id();



echo '<div class="custom-product-price" style="text-align:center;">';

echo '<p id="product-price-' . $product_id . '" style="font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;">Price: ' .  $default_price_html . ' </p>';

echo '</div>';



echo '<div class="custom-product-variations" style="text-align:center;">';

$attributes = $product->get_variation_attributes();



foreach ($attributes as $attribute_name => $options) {

    echo '<div class="variation-group">';

    foreach ($options as $index => $option) {

        $input_id = 'attribute_' . sanitize_title($attribute_name) . '_' . $product_id . '_' . $index;

        echo '<input type="radio" id="' . $input_id . '" class="variation-option" name="attribute_' . sanitize_title($attribute_name) . '_' . $product_id . '" value="' . esc_attr($option) . '" data-attribute_name="' . sanitize_title($attribute_name) . '" data-product_id="' . $product_id . '">';

        echo '<label for="' . $input_id . '">' . esc_html($option) . '</label>';

    }

    echo '</div>';

}

echo '</div>';



echo '<div class="custom-add-to-cart">';

echo '<button id="add-to-cart-button-' . $product_id . '" disabled>Add to Cart</button>';

echo '</div>';



echo '<script type="text/javascript">

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

    var productID = "' . $product_id . '";

    var variationOptions = document.querySelectorAll(".variation-option[data-product_id=\'" + productID + "\']");

    var priceElement = document.getElementById("product-price-" + productID);

    var addToCartButton = document.getElementById("add-to-cart-button-" + productID);

    var selectedVariationId = null;



    var availableVariations = ' . json_encode($available_variations, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT) . ';

    var defaultPriceHtml = ' . json_encode($default_price_html) . ';



    // Function to update the price display

    function updatePrice(priceHtml) {

        priceElement.innerHTML = "Price: " + priceHtml;

    }



    // Function to find and set the matching variation

    function findMatchingVariation(selectedAttributes) {

        return availableVariations.find(function (variation) {

            return Object.keys(selectedAttributes).every(function (key) {

                return variation.attributes[key] === selectedAttributes[key];

            });

        });

    }



    // Function to gather selected attributes

    function getSelectedAttributes() {

        var selectedAttributes = {};

        variationOptions.forEach(function (opt) {

            if (opt.checked) {

                var attrName = "attribute_" + opt.getAttribute("data-attribute_name");

                selectedAttributes[attrName] = opt.value;

            }

        });

        return selectedAttributes;

    }



    // Event listener for option changes

    variationOptions.forEach(function (option) {

        option.addEventListener("change", function () {

            var selectedAttributes = getSelectedAttributes();



            // Find matching variation

            var matchingVariation = findMatchingVariation(selectedAttributes);



            // Update the price and enable the Add to Cart button if a matching variation is found

            if (matchingVariation) {

                var priceHtml = "<span class=\"woocommerce-Price-amount amount\"><bdi><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol\">&#36;</span>" + matchingVariation.display_price.toFixed(2) + "</bdi></span>";

                updatePrice(priceHtml);

                selectedVariationId = matchingVariation.variation_id;

                addToCartButton.disabled = false; // Enable the Add to Cart button

            } else {

                updatePrice(defaultPriceHtml);

                selectedVariationId = null;

                addToCartButton.disabled = true; // Disable the Add to Cart button

            }

        });

    });



    // Add to Cart button click event

    addToCartButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {

        // Before proceeding, check if any variation is selected and valid

        if (!selectedVariationId) {

            // Stop the function from proceeding and show the appropriate alert

            event.preventDefault();

            alert("Please select a variation before adding to cart.");

            return;

        }



        // If variation is selected, proceed with the add-to-cart functionality

        var formData = new FormData();

        formData.append("action", "woocommerce_add_to_cart");

        formData.append("product_id", selectedVariationId); // Use the selected variation ID

        formData.append("variation_id", selectedVariationId);

        formData.append("quantity", 1);



        // Include selected attributes in the form data

        var selectedAttributes = getSelectedAttributes();

        for (var key in selectedAttributes) {

            if (selectedAttributes.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

                formData.append(key, selectedAttributes[key]);

            }

        }



        fetch("' . admin_url('admin-ajax.php') . '", {

            method: "POST",

            body: formData,

            credentials: "same-origin"

        })

        .then(function (response) {

            return response.json();

        })

        .then(function (data) {

            if (data.error) {

                alert("Error adding to cart: " + data.error);

            } else {

                alert("Product added to cart successfully!");



                // Optionally, update the cart count or show a success message

                var cartCountElement = document.querySelector(".cart-count");

                if (cartCountElement) {

                    cartCountElement.textContent = data.cart_count;

                }

            }

        })

        .catch(function (error) {

            alert("There was an error processing your request. Please try again.");

        });

    });

});

</script>'; 


do some debugging around the results of getSelectedAttributes and findMatchingVariation functions

Thanks. I have too many custom codes on my website. After reviewing all the code, I found that I mistakenly used the same class on 2 different custom codes, which is why the issue is causing it. The problem is solved.
